# Trouble with jquery link in html5 file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So here's my html code (Important part is in the triple quotations):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ToDoApp.css"/>
        """<script type="text/javascript" src="ToDoApp.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>"""

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list">
            <ol></ol>
        </div>
        <div class = "counter">
            <h4>Things to do:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class = "comment"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my .css connection is working perfectly, but my .js/jquery connection is just not functioning. I've tried looking up correct html syntax for including a link, and I tried alternating among a few different links to the jquery library. Is there something I'm missing here, have I put the link in the wrong place, or is the syntax funky? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `ToDoApp.js` in the same directory as the `HTML` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your ToDoApp.js relies on jQuery then you will need to change the order of your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ToDoApp.css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ToDoApp.js"></script>
```

Otherewise, the code that you have supplied shows not reliance on jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to debug issues with JS or CSS files not being included, is to monitor the network traffic with your browsers Debugging tools..  In `IE`, press F12, and then click on the Network tab.  Click 'Start Capturing' and re-navigate to the page.

If a 404 is returned, the path is probably wrong..  From here, you can look at the path the application actually tried to request its file from.

Other errors require different investigations.  If you don't even see the file show up in the requests list, then check the Console tab to see if the browser has logged any messages that may pertain to the situation.  As per Jeff's answer, if the problem is that something in your ToDoApp.js relies on jQuery, then you will see messages in the console that point to that issue, such as `$ is undefined`.